# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2+\sin(x)} dx$ using residues.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to evaluate
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2+\sin(x)} dx$$
using residues.

My attempt:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2+\sin(x)} dx = \int_\mathbb{D} \frac{\bigl(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\big)^2}{2 + \frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}} \frac{dz}{iz}
=\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{D}\frac{(z+z^{-1})^2}{z^2 + 4iz -1} dz.$$
The denominator is zero when
$$z = (-2\pm \sqrt{3})i.$$
For brevity, let $z^+ = (-2 + \sqrt{3})i$ and $z^- = (-2 - \sqrt{3})i$. Note only $z^+$ is in within $\mathbb{D}$ and so continuing from above
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{D} \frac{(z+z^{-1})^2}{(z-z^+)(z-z^-)} dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{D}\frac{F(z)}{z-z^+}dz$$
where
$$F(z) = \frac{(z+z^{-1})^2}{(z-z^-)}.$$
By Cauchy's Integral Formula,
$$2\pi i F(z^+) = \int_\mathbb{D}\frac{F(z)}{z-z^+}dz$$
and so our problem redduces to evaluating $\pi iF(z^+)$,
$$\pi iF(z^+) = \pi i \frac{\Big((-2 + \sqrt{3})i+\frac{1}{(-2 + \sqrt{3})i}\Big)^2}{((-2 + \sqrt{3})i-(-2 - \sqrt{3})i)}\\
= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\Big((-2 + \sqrt{3})i+\frac{1}{(-2 + \sqrt{3})i}\Big)^2\\
= -\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\Big(-2 + \sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{-2 + \sqrt{3}}\Big)^2.$$

This is where I run into a problem. Even before simplifying further I notice my solution will be negative, but graphically this clearly cannot be the case. I have repeated my calculation thrice yet still end up with the same conclusion. WolframAlpha shows the answer to be $-2(\sqrt{3}-2)\pi$.

If anyone can spot the error it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

After simplifying the radical I obtain $-2\sqrt{3}\pi$, so comparing with Wolfram's answer I am missing a $4\pi$ somewhere.

Comment: I have a solution to this question using some basic formulas(I have not yet come across the methods you have used) .As this does not point where is the mistake in your solution ,I am putting it as a comment.First of all ,use kings rule and then add the 2 equations,after which you will have $sin^2x $and $cos^2x$ terms which can be converted into $tan^2x$ after basic manipulation.It can be proceeded further easily.

Comment: Don't use $z^{-1}$. Simplify by writing $\frac1z$. Then you will realise that the integrand also has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Ah I see it now, careless on my part! Thank you very much!